# Return Mono.empty() from Mono.fromCallable

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to do something like below. In the Mono.fromCallable I run some block logic, then based on the value I either return Mono.empty() or the value so that it will either trigger the map or defaultIfEmpty.

```
            Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
                double number = Math.random();
                if (number < 0.5) {
                    return Mono.empty();
                }

                return number;
            })
            .map(number -> 1)
            .defaultIfEmpty(0)
```

This give an error since Mono.fromCallable expect a consistent return value. How do I adjust the code to make it work?

Comment: Just return null, it will be interpreted as an empty Mono. See docs: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#fromCallable-java.util.concurrent.Callable-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although returning `null` is usually prohibited in Reactor APIs, it is a valid value that `Callable` may return, and Reactor handles it correctly by transforming into an empty `Mono`:

```java
Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
    double number = Math.random();
    if (number < 0.5) {
        return null;
    }

    return number;
})
```